# How does the Rabbanut Harashit work?

Tags: rabbis, politics-government, state-of-israel, organizations

- Who picks the Chief Rabbi of Israel/Cities? Is it a vote of all citizens/Shuls/Politicians or all of the above?
- Who picks the lower Dayanim on the Rabbanut Beis Din? Is it the "Chief Rabbi" or some commitee?
- Who picks the Chief Rabbi of the Tzahal?

**EDIT**

- According to @Vram, there is a difference between the appointment of Ashkenazi Chief Rabbis and Sefardi. What is the difference?

Comment: I can't not ask...What's with the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under current Israeli law, the post of Chief Rabbi exists in only four cities - Jerusalem, Tel Aviv, Haifa, and BeerSheba. The Chief Rabbis are elected for 10 year terms.  There are 150 members of the board tasked with choosing the country's two chief rabbis. This board is a mix of orthodox and secular.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Rabbi

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Rabbinate_of_Israel

http://www.thejc.com/news/world-news/53092/chief-rabbi-selection-how-israel-does-it

Comment: This answer could be improved by stating how the 150 members of the board are picked.

Comment: When I know I can add it, however at the moment this is all I could find.